# Bootstrap Sidenav Styling on Desktop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar that has a menu that slides out from the right on click on mobile and small viewports. When viewed on a desktop, I'd like the standard bootstrap styles for navbar to be applied (no menu button, menu items appear inline directly in navbar). It appears to work as expected on small viewports, but on desktop it seems to still take the styles from the media query. I suppose there is something I'm overlooking. Can anyone out there advise as to what I'm doing wrong here?
 Code and example can be found [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/nzRI2Nz5OG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the media query just change min-width with max-width:500px instead, it Should work after that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I change to max width, it looks good in desktop, but in mobile, the menu animation no longer slides out from the right, but just behaves like the standard Bootstrap animation (drops down from top)

Comment: I think that's because the bootstrap breakpoint for small devices is 768 px so try changing max-width with 767px instead

Comment: This is definitely the correct path. I changed to max width with a setting of 768 like you've suggested and getting mixed (better) results. The navbar now displays correctly on desktop and mobile, however in tablet size (880 X 484) it's still behaving like the standard dropdown bootstrap navigation.

Comment: Ok just find the perfect setting with queries, there's the key, good coding.